# How many different results?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

$a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ are real numbers and you would like to calculate the equation below by adding as many paranteses as you want:

> a-b^c-d/e+f/g^h*i

What is the maximum amount of different results you can get by adding parantheses?

**Note:** Programming result is acceptable since you share the code and all possible different equations in terms of the letters rather than some garbage real number values.

Comment: real numbers as in, they can be anything? Or they should be the same during all the cases where parentheses are added?

Comment: @marius you are gonna choose any real number for each letter. no change in values for each letter  in the middle of the calculations of course and you cannot change their location either, just adding parantheses.

Comment: Am I missing something? I posted an answer that I think is correct, but it seems too trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but doen't this relate closely to

> Catalan-numbers?

Just look at

> the second comment [on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000108):
>  Number of ways to insert n pairs of parentheses in a word of n+1 letters. E.g., for n=2 there are 2 ways: ((ab)c) or (a(bc)); for n=3 there are 5 ways: ((ab)(cd)), (((ab)c)d), ((a(bc))d), (a((bc)d)), (a(b(cd))).

So the final answer is

> $C_9=1430$

There is an important detail left to be shown:

> Does every different grouping actually lead to different results?
>  There are three things to consider here:
>
>  1) As there is only one addition and one multiplication, different groupings will give different results if the numbers are well chosen. Otherwise (x+y)+z=x+(y+z) or (xy)z=x(yz) would apply: different parenthesisation would lead to the same result no matter how we choose the numbers.
>
>  2) It is also necessary there are no subtractions after the addition and no divisions after the multiplication. Otherwise x+(y-z)=(x+y)-z or x*(y/z)=(x*y)/z would apply, causing different parenthesizations leading to the same results.
>
>  3) We also have to take care of every interpretation being valid: that is no zeros in the denominators of the fractions, and at the exponentiations no negative bases with non-integer exponents. Although I don't go into all the details, I'm convinced this can be granted easily.

Comment: This is the upper bound. For example, $(a-b)^c-d/e$ is the same as $((a-b)^c-d/e)$ and $((a-b)^c-(d/e))$

Comment: I cannot see that is a problem. Those all are the same grouping of (((ab)c)(de)), aren't they? You just erased some unnecessary parentheses from the very same expression of $(((a-b)^c)-(d/e))$, I mean.

Comment: ok let say I ask the same question without only + and -'s. Your answer would be still 1430 different results? or if I asked with only * and /...

Comment: For the record, I wrote a program that performed my answer and then sorted the results and removed duplicates.  I ended up with this answer as well.

Comment: @Oray No, in that case it would be different because $(a+b)+c$ is the same as $a+(b+c)$, and that would have to be taken into account.  The question as it is written has no such problems I think.

Comment: Trenin is on the point. As the expression given in the original post does not have two operators with the same precedence next to each other, all the different groupings give different results. That wouldn't be true with $a+b+c$  or with $a+b-c$, as in that expression, operators with the same precedence are right next to each other, and that would reduce the number of different solutions down from 1430 to a number which is dependent on the actual expression, I think.

Comment: You can simplify the current expression to $a-X-Y+Z$, but all parenthesizations of this expression are different I think.

Comment: let say for this part: $f/g^h*i$, according to four 5 ways; $((f/g)^{h*i}), (((f/g)^{h})*i), ((f/(g^h))*i), (f/((g^h)i)), (f/(g^{h*i}))$  do you see which equation is the same among these?

Comment: Oh, yes, @Trenin, this seems to be an important observation indeed, and means that some of my comments above weren't 100% correct. But this does not change the answer to the question posted.

Comment: @Oray The 5 different equations from 'f/g^h*i' are: 1: $(\frac{f}{g})^h\times i$,  2: $(\frac{f}{g})^{h\times i}$, 3: $\frac{f}{g^h} \times i$, 4: $\frac{f}{g^h\times i}$, 5: $\frac{f}{g^{h\times i}}$.  All of these are different.

Comment: @Oray, the 'canonical' paranthesisation for $f/g^h*i$ is $((f/(g^h))*i)$, I think. I'm not sure that this is what you are asking, though.

Comment: After taking Trenin's comment into account, I think we can say the 1430 groupings are different, because there aren't two +s neither two *s in the original expression. Those are the only operator sequences which could be grouped two different ways and still give the same results: $(a+(b+c))=((a+b)+c)$ and $(a*(b*c))=((a*b)*c)$

Comment: @elias, I think you are right, I will recheck all details again and accept your answer since there is no case as I suggested previously in my equation :)

Comment: Thanks, @Oray, I also plan to update my answer with the details addressed in the comments, to have a much cleaner final answer.

Comment: @elias just a question - what about $(a-b^c-d)/((e+f)/(g^h\cdot i))$ as opposed to $(a-b^c-d)/((e+f)/(g^h))\cdot i$? They evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: @boboquack, for me it seems you're right, and also $(a-((b^c)-((d/e)+(f/g^h \cdot i)))=((a-((b^c)-(d/e)))+(f/g^h \cdot i))$. If I'm right these both collapse $C_4 \cdot C_2 \cdot C_2 \cdot C_1 = C_4 = 5$ cases (the number of possible groupings of $a-b^c-d$ and $f/g^h \cdot i$, as the shorter groups are still unique), so the final answer is $C_9-2(C_4-1)=1422$. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: @Trenin, in an earlier comment you noted you've found 1430 different values. How is that possible?

Comment: @elias Not sure why you are asking.  Do you think 1430 is not possible?  It is your accepted answer.  I wrote a program to find them and sorted the results.  That was a while ago, but I might be able to find the program again if you want.

Comment: @Trenin, sorry, I can understand these old results might not be at hand. Indeed it seems there is no possible input that gives 1430 different results. I just hoped you can doublecheck.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit: This is an oversimplification which is proven to be too high in the comments.  I'll leave it here, but note it is not the correct answer.***

There are 9 variables and 8 operators.  Lets define a system where we choose a pair of adjacent variables and apply the operator between them.  The result is another real number, which you can then put back into the equation, leaving you with one less variable and one less operation, on which you can apply your system again recursively.

Using that system, if you have $n+1$ variables with $n$ operations, you will basically go through $n$ rounds before you come up with an answer.  In the first round, you have $n$ choices for the adjacent variables.  In the second round, you will have $n-1$ choices, and so on.

So, the total number of choices is defined by $T_0=1$ and $T_n = n \times T_{n-1}$ where $n$ is the number of operators.

Thus, the theoretical maximum answer is a simple

> $T_n= n\times (n-1) \times (n-2) ... \times 2 \times 1 = n!$

So, in this case, there are

> $T_8 = 8! = 40320$ possible results

If we choose

> irrational, unrelated numbers

for each variable, we should be able to achieve all of these results.  The only real trick is

> ensure $a \gt b$ because the expression 'c-d/e+f/g^h*i' can be negative and if $a \lt b$, then $a-b$ is negative, and the entire expression will have an imaginary component.

Comment: I disagree. This only gives an upper bound. For example, there are no differences between the following two orders: 1. starting with b^c and then g^h and then the rest from let's say left-to-right; 2. starting with g^h, then b^c, and then the rest again.

Comment: @elias You are right - I thought I oversimplified and must be missing something!