# Pawns and Discs

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

There are $8$ pawns next to each other and by using any size of discs you need to cover all pawns. The conditions while putting discs is that:

- Every disc and every pawn is called an object.
- There has to be two objects in a disc.
- The pawns in the disc is not being counted as different objects for outer disc.

> So, how many different way to put these discs is there?

For example if this question was asked for  $4$ pawns the answer would be $5$ as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for the

> eighth [Catalan number](https://oeis.org/A000108), which equals 429. Many problems with this sort of "nested" structure end up being about Catalan numbers.

Comment: Oray seems to have [a thing for these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51336/8822).